# Куда делся модуль Qt Charts из PySide2?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, pyqt6, pyside6

В документации для версии **Qt** для **Python 5.15.2** был модуль `QtCharts`.
Для версии **Qt** для **Python 6.0.2** данного модуля в документации нету.
Такой импорт не работает:

```
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries, QValueAxis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Qt Charts` для **Qt6** **`не планируется к выпуску до 6.1.`**
https://www.qt.io/blog/add-on-support-in-qt-6.0-and-beyond